# How to modify WordPress side bar?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, sidebar

I'm trying to create a child theme of an existing template on wordpress. I would like to change the template of the sidebar. Not to change the functionalities but just to change the visual aspect.
Here is what I currently have : 
[image]

[image]

I would like to add the kind of underline and widgets you can see on the second picture. To do that I need to modify the template but I have no clue about how to do it.
Could you please help me if you know how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you access your theme files, you'll need to either go to Appearance > Editor then find `sidebar.php` or if you need to access the file via your server files, go to wp-content > themes > *theme-name* > `sidebar.php`.

Sidebar.php is the sidebar of your website, and any changes made here will be reflected across your main sidebar in the live site.

Comment: Ok but here is the content of my sidebar.php file : <?php

`if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {
 return;
}
?>

<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
 <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</div><!-- #secondary -->` . I don't see where I can change the display of the elements of the side bar.

Comment: I believe you should be able to find `sidebar-1` within Appearance > Widgets, it will be a container with a series of widgets within it.